# How to order by the same filed twice by condition

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this model :

```
public class Post {
    private Long expiryDate;  // A timestamp
}
```

And repository as :

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {
    Page<Post> findAllByOrderByExpiryDateDesc(Pageable pageable);
}
```

What I want to do:

When the expiry date has passed (post expired, current date greater than expiry date)  => orderBy desc

Else, When the expiry date not yet passed (post not expired)  => orderBy asc

**Example**: if I have the expiry date list: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday

and that today is Wednesday (Wednesday not yet expired).

**Wanted result**:

1. Wednesday
2. Thursday
3. Friday
4. Tuesday
5. Monday

Someone got any solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (with the help of @crizzis),
This Query work perfectly :

```
@Query(value = "from Post as p ORDER BY " +
        "CASE WHEN p. expiryDate > :currentTime THEN -p.expiryDate ELSE null END desc," +
        "CASE WHEN p. expiryDate < :currentTime THEN -p.expiryDate ELSE null END asc")
Page<Post> findAll(Long currentTime, Pageable pageable);
```

For native query (h2 database example)

```
SELECT * FROM Post p
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN p.expiryDate > currentTime THEN -p.expiryDate END desc,
CASE WHEN p.expiryDate < currentTime THEN -p.expiryDate END asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following query:

```
SELECT p FROM Post p
ORDER BY CASE
   WHEN p.expiryDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN p.expiryDate
   ELSE -p.expiryDate
END ASC
```

(you might need some casting to make it work, but since you didn't mention the RDBMS you're using, you'll need to check it out yourself)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response :D
I use spring data, so i can use native query or Spring data jpa query.
Your answer did not solve my problem, but it inspired me a lot to find the right answer,
this work perfectly : 
@Query(value = "from Post as p ORDER BY " +
            "CASE WHEN p.expiryDate > : CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN -p.expiryDate ELSE null END desc," +
            "CASE WHEN p.expiryDate < : CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN -p.expiryDate ELSE null END asc")